# Gradle Build Failed Due to PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException

Tags: gradle, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I trying to download the test.aero:test-4-1-schema-data:1.0.0 dependencies from my local GitLab Repository. However, I always receive 'PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException' when I run gradle build command.

The SSL certificate is self-signed. Is it must manually add cacerts? Any way to bypass the SSL check?

Error Log

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
> Could not resolve test:test-4-1-schema-data:1.0.0.
> Required by:
> project :
> > Could not resolve test.aero:test-4-1-schema-data:1.0.0.
> > Could not get resource 'https://gitlab.dev/api/v4/projects/2/packages/maven/test/test-4-1-schema-data/1.0.0/test-4-1-schema-data-1.0.0.pom'.
> > Could not HEAD 'https://control.dev:888/v1/AUTH_a741e82674cc4asdfasdfasf/packages/83/f8/83f814f7a92e365cbd79f9addceed185761a8d38a06a2d4350bb1fe4b7632b34/packages/8/files/23/test-4-1-schema-data-1.0.0.pom?temp_url_sig=1e01f6271cdef0177711360760229daa0a88b18f&temp_url_expires=1644474416'.
> > PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

build script

```
plugins {
id "org.springframework.boot" version "2.6.1"
id "io.spring.dependency-management" version "1.0.11.RELEASE"
id "java"
id "eclipse"
id "maven-publish"
id "io.franzbecker.gradle-lombok" version "5.0.0"
id "com.github.spotbugs" version "5.0.5"
}

repositories {
maven {
  url 'https://gitlab.dev/api/v4/projects/2/packages/maven'
  name 'gitlab'
}
 mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
compileOnly 'com.github.spotbugs:spotbugs:4.5.3'
implementation 'test.aero:test-4-1-schema-data:1.0.0'
implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest:2.6.1') {
    exclude group: "org.springframework.boot", module: "spring-boot-starter-logging"
}
implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.13.0'
implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml:2.13.0'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2:2.6.2'
implementation "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.22"

// Use JUnit test framework.
testImplementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.11.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
}


bootJar  {
 baseName = 'test-fxm-converter'
 version = '1.0.0'
}

publishing {
publications {
    maven(MavenPublication) {
        groupId = 'org.caas.mgr'
        artifactId = 'fxml-converter'
        from components.java
    }
}
 }
```

Comment: please share a little bit more information - how does your build look like, do you use any kind of premade image - is that maybe outdated? sharing your build configuration, or at least the important parts would be great

Comment: @SimonSchrottner what information do you need? let me know. I try to provide :) I did not use any premade image. The gradle version is 7.3.1

Comment: i assume you are running a pretty outdated local version of java - try to upgrade to a newer patch release of your version - this might help and improve it

Comment: and ensure that the certificate of your gitlab is also part of your trust store in java

Comment: @SimonSchrottner any way to skip ssl check?

Comment: It's best to add the missing gitlab certificate chain to your java trust store as Simon suggests. You can try changing protocol to http, and add line isAllowInsecureProtocol = true to maven repository declaration.  (the line might be allowInsecureProtocol true  - depends on gradle version) Insecure protocol may not work for publishing.